# How can I keep multiple controls in focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have a tree view on the left side. Selecting a node displays relevant information in a form on the right side.

Would I be able to keep the tree and any one control (textbox, combobox, checkbox) on the right in focus at the same time? This will enable a user to select a field, make a change, select another node, and without having to go back and select the same field again, just type and change the value of the same field.

Thanx.

**EDIT**
I suppose one could implement such behaviour manually:

```
private Control __cFocus;

private void {anyControl}_Focus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    __cFocus = (Control)sender;
}

private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    __cFocus.Focus();
}
```

I was just wondering if there exists an automatic / more elegant solution

**EDIT 2**
Ok, so it seems I'll have to implement it manually. Manual implementation it is then. However, now there seem to be another problem; not sure if I should ask this as a separate question.

When selecting a node the textbox gains focus as intended, but only when using the keyboard. It doesn't work when selecting a node with the mouse. First I thought that it might be a mouse event that's interfering, but stepping revealed that the `MouseUp` event fired first and then the `AfterSelect` event which sets the focus, so I don't think it's interfering. The textbox's `Enter` event is also fired, but for some reason it loses focus again to the tree.

Thanx

Comment: i believe you want to bind the values of tree and the other controll

Comment: like a databound information panel; but wouldn't that still remove focus from the information control, hence the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you cannot keep two controls in focus at the same time.  But what you can do is set the focus to the target control in the treeview AfterSelect event

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Focus();
    textBox1.SelectAll();
}
```

then in your textbox leave, save the changes, like so:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //save changes here
}
```

this way, everytime you select an item in the treeview, check your textbox for change and save as needed, then you will refocus on the textbox for your next edit

Comment: I have also tried a manual way - as suggested in my edited post - but using the mouse to select a node doesn't work. When focusing the tree and using the keyboad (up/down or first letters) it works though. This has led me to look for an alternative. Any suggestions on the mouse selection?

Comment: you probably need to subscribe to multiple events then.  Like mouseup, but you'll need to be careful that you don't execute the same function multiple time for each selection.

Answer (score 2):

There only can be **one** element having the focus!

But I have an idea for you that might solve your problem. Assuming you have a window with a TreeView and a TextBox. Set the HideSelection property of the TreeView to false and subscribe the AfterSelect event (like edeperson already answered) like this:

```
private void OnTreeViewAfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = e.Node.Text;
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Then subscribe the KeyDown event of the TextBox and do following in the event method:

```
private void OnTextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down))
    {
        treeView1.Focus();
        SendKeys.Send(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up ? "{UP}" : "{DOWN}");
    }
}
```

At last subscribe the Leave event of the TextBox and do following in the event method:

```
private void OnTextBoxLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
    {
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

And, voilá it should work like you expected it...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to focus on it , you can  use usercontrol. you can put your textbox on usercontrol   and set focus of this textbox on usercontrol using set properties on treeview select.

Answer (score 0):

No you may not, only one control may be in focus at any given time.

See Moonlight's comment for one way to achieve the behavior that you seek.